# Horizontal CSS menu is not smooth in certain layout scenarios

Tags: html, css, tree, menu, display

Currently working on the fine tuning the CSS horizontal tree with nested UL.
there are some issues when certain li is nested and the difference in the alignment or layout
Issue areas are highlighted in red

The layout is working for certain scenarios and certain other scenarios the alignment is not smooth.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    body {
    padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .tree {
    list-style: none;
    }

    .tree,
    .tree * {
    margin: 0;
    }

    .tree li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 2vw;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
    }
    .tree li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 5%;
    margin-top: 2px;

    }




    .tree li::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    left: 2px;
    top: 1%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    border-top: 5px solid red;
    width: 2vw;
    }




    .tree li:not(:last-of-type)::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    left: -2px;
    margin-left: -3px;
    top: 2%;
    border-top: 2px solid BLUE;
    width: 2vw;
    }
    /* ========================================================= */



    .tree li:not(:only-child):not(:last-of-type)::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    border-left: 2px solid blue;
    }
    .tree li:not(:only-child):not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type)::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    }


    .tree li:only-child::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
    border-left: 0px solid grey;
    }
    .tree li:only-child::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 2%;
    top: 14%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    border-left: 0px solid grey;
    }

    .tree li:only-last-child::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -5%;
    top: -20%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -24px;
    border-left: 10px solid yellow;
    }

    .tree li:only-last-child::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0%;
    top: 5%;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    }

    /* ========================================================= */

    .tree li:last-of-type::after {
    height: 50%;
    top: 0;            
    }

    .tree li:first-of-type::after {
    height: 50%;
    bottom: 0;           
    }

    .tree li:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type)::after {
    height: 100%;
    }

    .tree ul,
    .tree ol {
    padding-left: 2vw;
    position: relative;
    }

    .tree ul:not(:empty)::before,
    .tree ol:not(:empty)::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    width: 2vw;
    }



    .tree span {
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.33em 0.66em;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: blue;
    }

    .tree>li {
    padding-left: 0;
    }

    .tree>li::before,
    .tree>li::after {
    display: none;
    }

    ol,
    ul {
    counter-reset: section;
    }

    li span::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    /* content: counters(section, ".") " "; */
    font-family: monospace;
    }

    body {
    /* display: flex; */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    }







    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul class="tree">
    <li><span>Main</span>


    </li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="tree">
    <li>
    <span>BACKLOG</span>
    <ul>
    <li><span>Level1</span>

    <ul>
    <li><span>Level1.1</span>
    <ul>
    <li><span>Level1.2.1</span>

    <ul>
    <li><span>Level1.2.1.1</span></li>
    <li><span>Level1.2.1.2</span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Level1.2.2</span></li>
    </ul>

    </li>
    <li><span>Level1.2</span>
    <ul>
    <li><span>Level1.2.1</span>

    <ul>
    <li><span>Level1.2.1.1</span></li>
    <li><span>Level1.2.1.2</span>

    <ul>
    <li><span>Level1.2.1.2.1</span></li>
    <li><span>Level1.2.1.2.2</span></li>
    <li><span>Level1.2.1.2.3</span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Level1.2.1.3</span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Level1.2.2</span>


    <ul>
    <li><span>Level1.2.2.1</span></li>
    <li><span>Level1.2.2.2</span></li>
    <li><span>Level1.2.2.3</span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems somewhat got a simple resolution (fix was top: % to px) and arranged based on color to visualize what selectors / attributes we can try.
[Solution1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv9uz.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
body {
padding-top: 10px;
}
/* important for icont / status display of the element
.tree ul > li:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 2%;
margin-bottom: -2px;
border-top: 20px solid green;
width: 2vw;
}
*/
.tree {
list-style: none;
}

.tree,
.tree * {
margin: 0;
}

.tree li {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: flex-start;
position: relative;
padding-left: 2vw;
padding-bottom: 2vh;
}
.tree ul > li::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 5%;
margin-top: 2px;

}


.tree li::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
align-items: center;
left: 2px;
top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-right: -30px;
border-top: 2px solid grey;
width: 2vw;
}




.tree li:not(:last-of-type)::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
align-items: center;
left: 0px;
margin-left: -4px;
top: 0px;
border-top: 2px solid grey;
width: 2vw;
}
/* ========================================================= */



.tree li:not(:only-child):not(:last-of-type)::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 4px;
bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: -4px;
border-left: 2px solid blue;
}
.tree li:not(:only-child):not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type)::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 4px;
bottom: 0px;
top: 0px;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-bottom: -4px;
border-left: 2px solid brown;
}


.tree li:only-child::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0%;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-bottom: -6px;
border-left: 0px solid grey;
}
.tree li:only-child::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 2%;
top: 14%;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
border-left: 0px solid grey;
}

.tree li:only-last-child::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: -5%;
top: -20%;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: -24px;
border-left: 10px solid yellow;
}

.tree li:only-last-child::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0%;
top: 5%;
margin-top: -9px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border-left: 2px solid white;
}

/* ========================================================= */

.tree li:last-of-type::after {
height: 50%;
top: 0;            
}

.tree li:first-of-type::after {
height: 50%;
bottom: 0;           
}

.tree li:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type)::after {
height: 100%;
}

.tree ul,
.tree ol {
padding-left: 2vw;
position: relative;
}

.tree ul:not(:empty)::before,
.tree ol:not(:empty)::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0px;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-bottom: -3px;
border-top: 2px solid orange;
width: 2vw;
}



.tree span {
border: 1px solid;
text-align: center;
padding: 0.33em 0.66em;
background-color: yellow;
color: blue;
}

.tree>li {
padding-left: 0;
}

.tree>li::before,
.tree>li::after {
display: none;
}

ol,
ul {
counter-reset: section;
}

li span::before {
counter-increment: section;
/* content: counters(section, ".") " "; */
font-family: monospace;
}

body {
/* display: flex; */
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="tree">
<li><span>Main</span>

<ul>
<li><span>Level1</span>

<ul>
<li><span>Level1.1</span>
<ul>
<li><span>Level1.1.1</span>
<ul>
<li><span>Level1.1.1.1</span>
</li>
<li><span>Level1.1.1.2</span>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><span>Level1.1.2</span>
<ul>
<li><span>Level1.1.2.1</span>
</li>
<li><span>Level1.1.2.2</span>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><span>Level1.2</span>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>

</ul>
<ul class="tree">
<li>
<span>BACKLOG</span>
<ul>
<li><span>Level1</span>

<ul>
<li><span>Level1.1</span>
<ul>
<li><span>Level1.2.1</span>

<ul>
<li><span>Level1.2.1.1</span></li>
<li><span>Level1.2.1.2</span></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><span>Level1.2.2</span></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li><span>Level1.2</span>
<ul>
<li><span>Level1.2.1</span>

<ul>
<li><span>Level1.2.1.1</span></li>
<li><span>Level1.2.1.2</span>

<ul>
<li><span>Level1.2.1.2.1</span></li>
<li><span>Level1.2.1.2.2</span></li>
<li><span>Level1.2.1.2.3</span></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><span>Level1.2.1.3</span></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><span>Level1.2.2</span>


<ul>
<li><span>Level1.2.2.1</span></li>
<li><span>Level1.2.2.2</span></li>
<li><span>Level1.2.2.3</span></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```